# Cypress + yarn/npm won’t run a CLI command in `after:run`, only in `before:run`

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing, npm-scripts, yarnpkg-v2

I want Cypress to execute custom scripts before and after running the specs suite.

The [`before:run`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/before-run-api) and [`after:run`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-run-api) APIs look perfect for that.

But the same snippet that works perfectly in `before:run` doesn’t seem to work in `after:run`:

```
module.exports = {
    e2e: {
       setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
         on("before:run", details => {
            console.log("Before run:")
            exec("npm run cal", {}, handleExecOutput)
         })

         on("after:run", results => {
            console.log("After run:")
            exec("npm run cal", {}, handleExecOutput)
         })
      },
   },
};
```

The `cal` script is defined in package.json as simply calling the native `cal` command, as a minimal test.

This is logging "Before run" and the calendar (not exactly together) before running the specs, and *only* "After run" after running the specs. However, if I change `npm run cal` to simply `cal`, the command is executed in both cases.

I’ve tried it with and without promises, with yarn and npm, always the same result. What am I missing?

Comment: For now I’ve simply fixed it by not using these hooks, and just running `yarn test:setup && yarn cypress run; yarn test:teardown`. Seems to work perfectly. Sometimes I should just not overthink it!

Comment: I also have more flexibility this way: I can choose to run cypress without the setup/teardown steps for example, when I’m working on the tests and I don’t want to reset the database everytime.